# replacing the key value with another property in array of objects

Tags: javascript

merging array with object and returning an array with all the properties with array of object value or null

```
let object = {
  keys: {
    test1: {label: "Test_1"},
    test2: {label: "Test_2"},
    test3: {label: "Test_3"}
  }
}

let data = [{test1: "1", test2: "2", default:"123134" }, {test1: "1", test2: "2", default:"123134"}, {test1: "1", test3: "3"}, {test3: "3"}]
```

I am expecting the below array of objects

```
let expectedArray = [{Test_1: "1", Test_2: "2", Test_3: null ,default:"123134" }, {Test_1: "1", Test_2: "2", Test_3: null,  default:"123134"}, {Test_1: "1", Test_3: "3", Test_2:null }, {Test_3: "3", Test_1: null, Test_2: null}]
```

Tried below snippet

```
let res = data.map(o => {
  let obj = {}
  let c = Object.keys(o).forEach(aa => {
      obj[object.keys[aa].label] = o[aa]
  })
  return obj
})
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: i didnt undestand

Comment: He mean that what have you tried so far and where have you struck?

Comment: `{Test 1: "1", Test 2: "2", Test 3: null ,default:"123134" }` Is not a valid object

Comment: updated the key

Comment: updated with the snippet tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace existent key of object and rebuild new objects.

```js
var object = { keys: { test1: { label: "Test 1" }, test2: { label: "Test 2" }, test3: { label: "Test 3" } } },
    data = [{ test1: "1", test2: "2", default: "123134" }, { test1: "1", test2: "2", default: "123134" }, { test1: "1", test3: "3" }, { test3: "3" }],
    templates = Object.values(object.keys).map(({ label }) => ({ [label]: null })),
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        ...templates,
        ...Object
            .entries(o)
            .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k in object.keys ? object.keys[k].label : k]: v }))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i need to get all the keys, the expected array of each object consist of every key. Can you check the expectedData in the question

Comment: i am trying update the structure in a different way, can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339879/building-a-different-array-structure-from-array-of-objects-and-keys-based-on-so